# Iphone App Communication

Tags: iphone, objective-c

i  have two iphone application one for user side App and other one is for admin side App i want to communicate the both App with each other ...Mean when the user send order the admin application received the user order on his/her own admin App.

Is it Possible to communicate the Two App with each other .????

Comment: What about push-notifications via your own server?

Comment: i want that when my user app send order for product or service that order will directly send to the admin app ..

Comment: Push-notifications will solve your task

Comment: ok i will try thank u sir ...... i will be use two push_notification one in user app and 2nd in admin app for connection ?

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to have both apps talk to the same service in the cloud.  It sounds like there's a concept of sending and receiving orders so having data on a server that both apps use would be a very common approach.

For the server in the cloud, it could be web services, REST/JSON etc...  Beyond hosting your own service in the cloud you could look at services like Azure (Microsoft), AWS (Amazon) and Heroku (Rails).  Parse.com is one aimed at ease of use and iPhone.

Each of those services have different data storage options.

Comment: thxx  sir but sir my question is lil different i want that when my user side app order some product or service that product or service order directly send to the admin app ..is it possible?

Comment: understood - in that case, both apps would communicate with the same servie in the cloud (web service).  When one app submits the data - it send it to the service.  The other reads the data from the service.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what kind of connection between apps you want to use. You can use game kit to send information using bluetooth. Or you can set up a server to manage the information exchange. I believe there are much more other ways. You need to be more precise when defining what you want.

Comment: thxx sir but sir my question is lil different i want that when my user side app order some product or service that product or service order directly send to the admin app ..is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use push-notifications for that purposes:

1. From client app send new data to server.
2. Server should process new data and send push-notification to server app to appropriate device.
3. Server app should handle push-notification.